# Build a secure LLM RAG system on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, large-language-model, aws-networking

I'm developing an AWS architecture for a Retrieval Augmented Generation (RAG) system:

[image: AWS Architecture for RAG LLM]

1. Data (pdf, docx, txt, png, etc.) ingested and pre-processed are stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.
2. A Lambda function is triggered to orchestrate the embedding process.
3. The Lambda function uses an embedding model from Amazon Bedrock to generate embeddings of the document.
4. The embeddings are stored in a Mongo Database that acts as a vector database.
5. The user asks a question through the UI/UX frontend hosted in an AWS Amplify instance, and the question is forwarded to the Amazon API Gateway.
6. The API request is managed by the API Gateway Endpoint and triggers the Lambda function for the application orchestration.
7. The Lambda function retrieves the correct embedding vector correlated to the user question.
8. The Lambda function also retrieves the chat history from the DynamoDB database.
9. The context retrieved from the MongoDB Database and the chat history are augmented in the prompt for the request to Amazon Bedrock LLM model, which gives back an answer.
10. The answer from the LLM is verified by another Lambda function triggered from the Lambda Orchestrator Function.
11. The answer is forwarded to the UI/UX frontend.

**SECURITY**

Now, in terms of security, I don't want the system to be exposed to the public Internet (except for the front-end web app, that of course has to be public) therefore I'm putting the RDS MongDB database and all the Lambda functions inside the VPC (I know, technically the Lambda is always inside a VPC owned by the Lambda service, but in this case the Lambda functions are drawn inside my account VPC just to specify that they are configured to access resources in my account VPC).
As you can see the connection with the S3 bucket and DynamoDB database is through a VPC Gateway Endpoint.
While the connection with Amazon Bedrock service is through VPC Interface Endpoint (AWS PrivateLink).

**QUESTION**

Now my question is related to the connection between the front-end app and the API Gateway and the Lambda Orchestrator function.
In particular, can a public API Gateway endpoint interact with the in-VPC Lambda Orchestrator function? Or do I need to set up an API Gateway private endpoint in the same VPC of the in-VPC Lambda function to allow communication?
If I change the API Gateway to be private endpoint, how can I establish communication between the public front-end and the private API Gateway?

Comment: If I understand your intention with steps 10 and 11, your orchestrator Lambda function, once invoked, cannot receive inbound connections. It can make requests that yield responses, but other components cannot make connections to it.

Comment: I changed a little bit the architecture in order to be more clear in the steps 10 and 11. Basically the Validation Lambda function is triggered by the Orchestrator Lambda function after the Orchestrator function received the answer from the LLM (Amazon bedrock). So the validator function can only be triggered by the orchestrator function.

Comment: On the question of API Gateway invoking the orchestrator Lambda function, yes public APIG can invoke that Lambda function, regardless of its networking. Lambda function invocation is done by the AWS Lambda service control plane and your function's configured VPC networking is immaterial to that process (though VPC networking is obviously relevant to the function's subsequent ability to connect to other internal/external endpoints).

Comment: To the last part of your question, "If I change the API Gateway to be private endpoint..." - you would still need a pub APIG for the frontend app to work. From pub APIG, you would do a VPC Link -> NLB -> pvt APIG.

However, there is no real need in the use case you have defined. An example use case could be is when you want all internal resources to go through your pvt APIG. Say you have 100s of pvt Lambda or some cron compute to pre-process RAG metadata or update the vector db (Mongo), etc. That helps keep the internal networking clean.